# How do I group by a field's lower value when that field has multiple values? Google Bigquery and SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, greatest-n-per-group

If I need a string field after using group by, but this field has two possible values, how do I make sure the field with the lower value is showing when I group?

For example, I need the a "starts_at" string field included in my analysis. However, within this field when I group, there will be two possible string values:

1. 2019-07-07 15:00:00
2. 2019-07-07 15:55:00

When grouping, how do I make sure that only the first string(2019-07-07 15:00:00) is selected since that is the correct value?

If easier, I can convert this to a date time field so that it is in the format: "2019-07-07 13:35:00 UTC" if that makes it easier to group the values with the "lower" time value.

Language: SQL
Database: Google Bigquery via Google Cloud

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using, then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You shouldn't be storing DATE values in "string columns" to begin with.

Comment: I totally agree the date should not be stored as a string...we are part of a larger org that has data automatically pumped in to a shared database for everyone to query from, and due to the size and limitations I cannot change the original formatting. I can however, convert this to a date time field so that it is in the format: "2019-07-07 13:35:00 UTC" if that makes things easier. I'll try the below minimum formula too. I was thinking it could be simpler grouping off of the string first before converting to a datetime.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I have designed databases in BigQuery that store dates as strings.  It is a very reasonable option in BigQuery if you want local-time with timezone.

Comment: I am not the one designing nor will it be changed, only providing the context of the issue I am trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

Use `MIN()`:

```
MIN(col)
```

This will return the smaller value "alphabetically".  This also corresponds to the earlier date (your apparent definition of "lower value").